# How to extract the following using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trim

Example: `Front Office Manager 0105212000`

Only need `10521200`, so I am dropping the first and last characters.

Before:

```
0105212000
```

After:

```
10521200
```

Here's what I came up with so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, right(DESCRIPTION, 9) as 'DESC', DESCRIPTION 
FROM LABORLEVELENTRY
WHERE LABORLEVELDEFID = '201'
  AND INACTIVE = '0'
ORDER BY NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME,
  SUBSTRING(DESCRIPTION, 2, LEN(DESCRIPTION)-2) as 'DESC',
  DESCRIPTION 
FROM LABORLEVELENTRY
WHERE LABORLEVELDEFID = '201'
  AND INACTIVE = '0'
ORDER BY NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ( DESCRIPTION , 2 , LEN(DESCRIPTION)-2 )
```

Starting on the second character, select everything else but the last character

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select left(right('Front Office Manager 0105212000', 9), 8)
```

So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, 
    left(right(DESCRIPTION, 9), 8) as 'DESC', DESCRIPTION   
FROM LABORLEVELENTRY 
WHERE LABORLEVELDEFID = '201'   
    AND INACTIVE = '0' 
ORDER BY NAME
```